# Parsing a logic formula

Tags: c++, parsing

I recently made a little program that shouldparse a logic formula (given in conjunctive normal form). I do the parsing with reloaded `operator>>` but I am not very satisfied with the workaround I used to get those operators recognized from a file different from the file they are implemented in.

When I need those operators I have to write the following at the top of the file:

```
extern std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, class-name&);
extern std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const class-name&);
```

Here are the part I would be glad to have a review of:

```
#include "formula.hh"
#include "clause.hh"

#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

extern std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Clause& lhs);
extern std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream&, const Clause& lhs);

[...]

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& stream, Formula& lhs) {
    std::string cur_line("");
    unsigned int var_max_expected = 0;
    unsigned int nb_clauses_expected = 0;
    bool clause_read = false;
    bool intro_read = false;

    while (getline(stream, cur_line)) {
        Clause c;
        if (cur_line[0] == 'c') {} /* Comment skip */
        else if ((sscanf(cur_line.c_str(), "p cnf %d %d", &var_max_expected, &nb_clauses_expected)) == 2) {
            if (!intro_read)
                intro_read = true;
            else
                std::cerr << "Warning : Intro already read and overwritten!" << std::endl;
            if (clause_read)
                std::cerr << "Warning : Intro was not the first command of the file!" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::istringstream is(cur_line);
            is >> c;
            lhs.insert(c);
        }
        c.clear();
    }

    if (!intro_read)
        std::cerr << "Warning: Intro missing" << std::endl;
    else {
        if (var_max_expected != Var::max_index())
            std::cerr << "Warning: Bad number of variables. Found: " << Var::max_index() << ". Expected: " << var_max_expected << "." << std::endl;
        if (nb_clauses_expected != lhs.size() + 1)
            std::cerr << "Warning: Bad number of found. Found: " << lhs.size() << ".     Expected: " << nb_clauses_expected << "." << std::endl;
    }

    return stream;
}

#ifdef FORMULA_DEBUG


int
main (void) {
    Formula f;

    std::cin >> f;
    std::cout << f << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif /* FORMULA_DEBUG */
```

The relevant part in clause.hh, clause.cc and formula.hh are listed below:

**formula.hh**

```
#ifndef FORMULA_HH
#define FORMULA_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include "clause.hh"

class Formula : public std::set<Clause> {
    public:
    [...]
        /**
         * @brief Allow a Formula to be used with output streams.
         */
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Formula& rhs);

        /**
         * @brief Allow a Formula to be used with input streams.
         */
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Formula& lhs);

};
#endif
```

**clause.hh**

```
#ifndef CLAUSE_HH
#define CLAUSE_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include "truthvalue.hh"
#include "var.hh"

class Clause : public std::set<std::pair<Var *, bool>> {
    public:
    [...]

       /**
         * @brief Allow a Clause to be used with output streams.
         */
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Clause& rhs);

        /**
         * @brief Allow a Clause to be used with output streams.
         */
        friend std::istream& operator<<(std::istream& stream, Clause& lhs);

};
#endif
```

**clause.cc**

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "clause.hh"

[...]

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Clause& rhs) {
    os << rhs.to_str();
    return os;
}

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& is, Clause& lhs) {
    int nb;
    bool first_item = true;

    while(is >> nb) {
        if (nb == 0) break;

        int var = std::abs(nb);
        Var& v = Var::declare(var);
        bool polarity = (nb / var == 1)
                      ? true
                      : false
                      ;

        lhs.insert(std::make_pair(&v, polarity));
    }

    return is;
}
```

Do you have any ideas to get them recognized everywhere? If you need additional information I can provide them.

Samples test cases for parsing can be found [here](https://github.com/Lithrein/SATSolver/tree/testing/tests) and the whole code which is doing the parsing is [here](https://github.com/Lithrein/SATSolver/blob/propre/src/).

The compile line is the following:

```
g++/clang++ truthvalue.cc var.cc clause.cc formula.cc -DFORMULA_DEBUG -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simplify the boolean ternary**

You write:

```
    bool polarity = (nb / var == 1)
                  ? true
                  : false
                  ;
```

But `nb / var == 1` already is a boolean, so the ternary is completely superfluous and may be deleted:

```
    bool polarity = (nb / var == 1);
```